# Spliting an array length in to another array as ranges for every 20 count insert new range until end

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have no idea how to even do what I want, but I want to take an array length in my case the number of users and split that number into groupings of 20. Thus, if the length was 100 the array end result would be

array = ['0-19','20-29','30-39','41-49','50-59', '60-69', etc].
These ranges are how I filter my data because im doing a special project there is no other way to filter the data because its returned based on the range i feed it. however, I dont know another way to limit the results.

Comment: So you want an array looking just like that, with those numbers, right? Or is that just a clever way to try and show that you want an array with the actual users split by some number, or ... ?

Comment: You have one grouping of 20, followed by groupings of 10, in your example.  Also, what if you cannot exactly divide the array size by the desired grouping size?

Comment: Then there's `41-49`, which isn't even 10 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var arr = [/* array having `length` equal to or greater than 100 */]
, n = 0
, j = 20
, len = Math.ceil(arr.length / j)
, res = [];

do {
  res[n] = arr.splice(0, j);
  ++n;  
} while (res.length < len);

// do stuff with `res`
// console.log(res);
```

---

```js
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tempor rhoncus magna at rhoncus. Curabitur egestas urna elementum, ultrices risus eget, faucibus neque. Quisque mauris nisi, porta feugiat massa vitae, tincidunt vehicula mi. Morbi egestas turpis vel odio malesuada, at rutrum ligula tempus. Etiam in blandit ante. Aliquam sit amet luctus enim. Vestibulum pellentesque lacus nec suscipit convallis. Donec sodales turpis in malesuada elementum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nullam efficitur, lectus a dapibus scelerisque, nisl est hendrerit sem, eu imperdiet lacus elit ac dolor. In iaculis risus quam, ut cursus tellus mollis ac. Praesent porta arcu et tellus tempus lacinia. Duis condimentum tristique ligula sit amet aliquam.";

var arr = text.split(" ")
, arr = arr.concat.apply(arr, arr);

var n = 0
, j = 20
, len = Math.ceil(arr.length / j)
, res = [];

do {
  res[n] = arr.splice(0, j);
  ++n;  
} while (res.length < len);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are asking, or even what language you are working with, but I will do my best to help. It sounds as though you might want to look into jagged arrays; however, depending on your needs (and assuming you are working in an object-oriented language), you might want to create a class that can house your data and methods that access and modify values. Depending on the language, you can usually split an array with a keyword such as 'split', or maybe something in the form of myNewArray = myOldArray[0..9]. It would help if we had some code or more information.

Good luck

Just noticed this is a JavaScript question and wanted to mention that array.slice might help